# Find Groups that don't contain all records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I feel like I should be able to get this and I'm just having a brain fart.  I've simplified the problem to the following example:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID int);
DECLARE @B TABLE (GroupID char(1), ID int);

INSERT @A VALUES (1);
INSERT @A VALUES (2);
INSERT @A VALUES (3);

INSERT @B VALUES ('X', 1);
INSERT @B VALUES ('X', 2);
INSERT @B VALUES ('X', 3);

INSERT @B VALUES ('Y', 1);
INSERT @B VALUES ('Y', 2);

INSERT @B VALUES ('Z', 1);
INSERT @B VALUES ('Z', 2);
INSERT @B VALUES ('Z', 3);
INSERT @B VALUES ('Z', 4);
```

So table A contains a set of some records.  Table B contains multiple copies of the set contained in A with Group IDs.  But some of those groups may be missing one or more records of the set.  I want to find the groups that are missing records.  So in the above example, my results should be:

```
GroupID
-------
Y
```

But for some reason I just can't wrap my head around this, today.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This kind of requirement just automatically triggers a WHERE NOT EXISTS response in my brain....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awesome use-case for [relational division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29)! ([Here's a must-read blog post about it](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/))

```
SELECT DISTINCT b1.GroupID
FROM @B b1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM @A a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM @B b2
    WHERE b1.GroupID = b2.GroupID
    AND b2.ID = a.ID
  )
);
```

How to read this?

> I want all distinct `GroupIDs` in `@B` for which there is a record in `@A` for which there isn't a record in `@B` with the same `@A.ID`

In fact, this is the "remainder" of the relational division.

Comment: D'oh!  Yup.  This was the syntax I was trying to build.  But for some reason it just didn't come to me.  (Time to take a break, I think.)  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @DeadZone: No problem. I guess most people (including myself) need to look that up every time we need it. Just remember the term "relational division", though. That's easy to Google

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen that term, before.  I'll have to spend a little time checking out that wiki page.  :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   SELECT GroupID ,COUNT(GroupID )
    FROM @a INNER JOIN @b
    ON @a.id=@b.id
    GROUP BY GroupID 
    HAVING COUNT(GroupID )<(SELECT count(*) FROM @a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the combinations that are missing.

```
select FullList.*
from (select distinct a.ID,
             b.GroupId
             from @A a
             cross join @B b) FullList
left join @B b
on FullList.ID = b.ID
and FullList.GroupID = b.GroupID
where b.ID is null
```

The answer to your question would just be the same but with the first line:

```
select distinct FullList.GroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the combinations that are missing.

```
  select FullList.*
  from (select distinct a.ID,
                      b.GroupId
        from @A a
        cross join (select distinct db.GroupId from @B db) b
       ) as FullList
  left join @B b
  on FullList.ID = b.ID
  and FullList.GroupID = b.GroupID
  where b.ID is null
```

The answer to your question would just be the same but with the first line:

```
select distinct FullList.GroupID
```